# Java Stream GroupingBy collect in custom object

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, grouping

I have a Temperature Class

```
class Temperature {
    double minTemp;
    double maxTemp;
    String city;
    String country;
}
```

I have another class that maintains a collection of Temperature

```
class Temperatures {
    List<Temperature> temperatures;
}
```

I want to group the temperatures by countryName using streams.

What I want is

```
public Map<String, Temperatures> temperaturesByCountry()
```

But I am unable to get the Temperatures as map value using stream, what I get is List of Temperature.

My groupingBy implementation is following

```
Map<String, List<Temperature>> result = this.getTemperatures()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Temperature::getCountry));
```

I want to get `Map<String, Temperatures>` instead of `Map<String, List<Temperature>>`

How can I achieve this.?

Comment: Could you tell me please the logic for class Temperatures ? Thank you

Comment: @Echoinacup Temperatures class contains List of Temperature and some other functions having an average, max and min temperatures. This contains a list so that we can group this easily on countries and cities.

Comment: @HammadNaeem thank you:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have constructor `Temperatures(List<Temperature> temperatures)`
this should do the trick:

```
Map<String, Temperatures> result = 
       this.getTemperatures()
           .stream()
           .collect(groupingBy(Temperature::getCountry, 
                               collectingAndThen(toList(), Temperatures::new)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could have combined a `Map.forEach` with your existing information as:

```
Map<String, Temperatures> temperaturesByCountry = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<Temperature>> result = this.getTemperatures()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Temperature::getCountry));
result.forEach((k, v) -> temperaturesByCountry.put(k, new Temperatures(v)));
```